# How Can I install two version of opennlp?

Tags: windows, batch-file, opennlp, system-variable, system-paths

I want to install opennlp-1.6.0 and opennlp-1.5.3 on windows
i've tried it like this,
added the system variables

[image]

and the path

[image]

when I open the command prompt and type opennlp, output is as expected

```
C:\>opennlp
OpenNLP 1.6.0. Usage: opennlp TOOL  
where TOOL is one of:
Doccat                            learnable document categorizer
DoccatTrainer                     tr.............
```

but when I type opennlpl, this is what happens!

```
C:\>opennlpl
'opennlpl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Is the `opennlpl` really exist ?

Comment: i've given opennlpl_home right?
isn't that how it works?

Comment: No, it isn't. It's just a system variable name. You must have an `opennlpl` executable in your `%OPENNLPL_HOME%`

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Use both `opennlp` at the same time ? You should remove one of the paths & call the executable with the path directly

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/63837985@N07/27115209892/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112771/discussion-between-nuwanda-and-raptor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your opennlpl to work, you must have `opennlpl.bat` file in the root folder.
you must be having `opennlp.bat` in both the root folders which is why it isn't working.

But having two versions my guess is you want to train your models using both versions, you can train your models using `opennlp-1.5.3` which are compatible for higher version also but the vice-versa isn't true.
so, just configure it for `opennlp-1.5.3` and you should be fine.